# ld cannot find -lstdc++ when trying to build tools locally without sudo

Tags: build, cmake, compilation, linker, ld

i'm trying to compile a tool **without sudo** (to install locally) using cmake and it seems ld can't find libstdc++:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

and my ld search paths are:

```
$ ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib")
```

and there is a libstdc++ under `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`,

my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has included `/usr/lib64/`

Questions:
1. is it because of exact name match that caused 'ld' not to find the library?

2. how to make this visible for ld without 'sudo'?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to have `libstdc++.so` file (without so-version) too. Usually, this file is a link to the highest so-versioned file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, is this something we could pass to cmake config before calling 'make'? quite new to cmake options here, if you don't mind giving a bit cmake snippet. Thanks!

Comment: Again, this is **not a CMake issue**. Given plain library name, like `stdc++`, **the linker** (`ld`) doesn't search files with so-version (with extension like `.so.<version>`). For successful linking, on your system you should have a file *without* a so-version.

Comment: »» my LD_LIBRARY_PATH has included /usr/lib64/ «« : `libstdc++.so` is **not** usually in /usr/lib64/ → Fedora example `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/`  . ( Slackware has `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so` )

Comment: @KnudLarsen, i do have: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libstdc++.so -> /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks! could this "libstdc++" file be a symbolic link to the .so version: libstdc++ -> libstdc++.so.6? I guess this would require a sudo privilege.

Comment: It seems that linker should find file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libstdc++.so`. You may try to add `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2` into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev adding this path indeed solved my problem! If you want to put your comments into an answer, i'd be happy to accept that. One minor note though: why ld would be happy to just find a .so version in this case?